# Automapper not populating destination from source

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a simple test solution which consists of two projects (a 'business' layer and a Data Access layer) using Catel to tie the two together - works fine, no problems.

However, have been reading about how useful AutoMapper can be for helping to move data around such a setup by allowing easy population of DTO's and decided to give it a look...that's when my problems started!

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1, VS 2013 Express for Desktop and accessing a SQL Server Express 14 db - no problems with data retrieval and data displays correctly in my views.

AutoMapper was added using NuGet.

In order to use AutoMapper I've set up the following in my App.xaml.cs

```
private void InitializeAutomapper()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Result, ResultDto>();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

This code is the first item called inside my 'OnStartup'.

A service in my business layer makes a call to the Data Access layer and retrieves a list of Result entites.

Subsequently, I take a single entity from this list and use that in the AutoMapper mapping call.

I'm trying to populate a resultDTO from this single entity, using the following

```
Result res = ResultList.First();
ResultDto resultDTO = Mapper.Map<Result, ResultDto>(res);
```

'res' is correctly populated with data but resultDTO is filled with the default values for the individual data types (in = 0, string = null, DateTime = {01/01/0001 00:00:00}) ie; *no values are mapped from the source to the destination*.

There are References in both projects to AutoMapper and AutoMapper.Net and no errors are raised - it just doesn't work as advertised...

I'm not slagging off the software, just asking what ***I'm*** doing wrong!

I realise there isn't much code to work on here but, in truth, what is posted here is pretty much all I've added to try out AutoMapper. I can see, conceptually how useful it could be - I just need to figure out how to make it happen so any help/comments gratefully received...:)

**EDIT**
@Andrew, as requested -

Result Class:

```
public partial class Result
{
    public int Div { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public int FTHG { get; set; }
    public int FTAG { get; set; }
    public string FTR { get; set; }
}
```

ResultDTO Class:

```
public class ResultDto
{
    int Div { get; set; }
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    string AwayTeam { get; set; }
    int FTHG { get; set; }
    int FTAG { get; set; }
    string FTR { get; set; }

    // Added tonight to try and get it to work
    public ResultDto()
    {
        Div = 0;
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        HomeTeam = null;
        AwayTeam = null;
        FTHG = 0;
        FTAG = 0;
        FTR = null;
    }
}
```

@stuartd, the following is used to retrieve the ResultList from which Result is obtained:

```
// Produce a list of DataLayer.Result entities.
 var ResultList = (from x in dbContext.Results.Local
                   where x.HomeTeam == team.TeamName.ToString() || x.AwayTeam == team.TeamName.ToString()
                   orderby x.Date
                   select x).ToList();
```

Please note 'team.Teamname' is passed into the above from an external source - seems to be working fine.

So to sum up -

1. I produce ResultList as a list of Result entities.
2. Fill Result with the first entity in the list.
3. Try to map this Result entity to ResultDTO
4. Fail :(

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you show the `Result` and `ResultDto` classes?

Comment: Are you getting the `Result` via EF? There are complications if the source object is an EF proxy, one solution is to use the [Queryable Extensions to AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, class members are declared `private` unless otherwise specified so the `ResultDto` properties aren't visible outside of the class.

```
public class ResultDto
{
    int Div { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

needs to be

```
public class ResultDto
{
    public int Div { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I am a total idiot! This has to be a classic example of 'more haste less speed' - of course, you're right. I was in such a rush to try out this cool new stuff I made a noob mistake...woe is me, thrice woe!

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper can work out the type you are mapping from from the arguments provided. Try this:

```
ResultDto resultDTO = Mapper.Map<ResultDto>(res);
```

**UPDATE** 
This is wrong, or at least won't help. We need to see the source and destination classes as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You *can* do this, but it will make absolutely no difference

Comment: yeah. I wasn't sure which way round the type parameters went and was thinking it might be `<TDestination, TSource>` - but I am wrong there I think.

Comment: Ugh - that wouldn't have even compiled. Ignore me. I'm having a dumb moment!